# Historical data from Twitter using REST API

Tags: php, twitter-rest-api

I am developing a PHP application using the Twitter API.

I have already achieved the data extraction from REST API using some queries
and then i have stored it in a MongoDB instance which can later be mined and accessed by my web application.

I want to  get historical data from Twitter.

- Is this possible ?
- Could you help me by providing query that can I use?

Thanks